# Dismiss popover view by pressing on a button on content view

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller, dismiss

I am implementing a settings view which be loaded as a content view of a popover controller in the main view, and the problem is:

There are 2 buttons on the settings view: Cancel and Done which are to abort or save and apply changes, and then dismiss the popover view, I already pass the popoverController instance from main view to the settings view and then call:

[popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

But nothing happen, the popover view still visible until I tap somewhere outside of it. I already search on the internet but not found answer yet.

Does anyone know how to do this please help me!

Comment: unfortunately, Apple don't want us to dismiss popover view programmingly

Comment: are you sure popoverController is not nil?

Comment: @SonNguyen This is not true see [dismissPopoverAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPopoverController/dismissPopoverAnimated:)